# Xamarin Forms - Hide Burger Menu

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, titlebar

Since the release of XF 3.2, it provided the ability to create your own custom TitleBar. This feature works well but I have a couple of problems that I am hoping someone can help me with.

I am trying to hide the Burger Menu icon, but so far I have not been able to.

I can hide the Back Button by doing the following:

NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"

This does however still leave a slight vertical bar on the left side of the TitleBar, so if someone knows how to also remove that then great.

I was expecting the same code to also hide the Burger Menu icon but this is still present so I'm hoping someone can help me to remove this.

Alternatively, if anyone knows of a way I can either change the icon (to use my own) or to change the colour of it (as it is always white and I want it to be black), then that would be great.

Cheers...

Comment: Not sure if that's what you mean, but IsPresented property can easily be changed! I have the following on the MD Page:  IsPresented="{Binding IsMenuOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"  So I can open/close that menu from anywhere.

Comment: That isn't quite what I want - ideally I want to be able to remove the icon altogether (like you can with the back button) as I plan to use my own icon to open the menu.

If this can't be done then I would accept just being able to change the colour of the icon.  The problem with this is all other icons on my Toolbar are black and the default Burger Menu icon is white.

So basically I want to either change the colour of the default icon or remove it completely so that I can use my own.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyout-behavior) you can hide the hamburger button and implicitly disable the flyout menu using:

- Globally inside AppShell (or whatever named), also you can change the [hamburger icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyout-icon)

```
<Shell>
...
     FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
     FlyoutIcon="flyouticon.png"
..
</Shell>
```

- Or hide it only in some pages:

```
<ContentPage>
...
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
</ContentPage>
```