# How do I use a NavigationPageRenderer in my Xamarin application to customize the top navigation bar?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, custom-renderer

I hoped I could use the `Shell.TitleView` to define the top navigation bar of my Xamarin application’s pages (the one with the hamburger icon, the back button, etc). Unfortunately, it doesn’t let you center the text perfectly, as you can read [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/141869/how-to-center-a-text-using-the-titleview-feature) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613454/xamarin-forms-shell-titleview-does-not-center-image).

I already made other custom renderers, but I’m experiencing difficulties implementing the `NavigationPageRenderer`. This is the code I copied from the Web:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomNavigation), typeof(CustomNavigationRenderer))]
namespace MyNamespace {
    internal class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer {
        public CustomNavigationRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

            if (toolbar == null) return;

            for (var i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++) {
                var x = toolbar.GetChildAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don’t know what this code does, and I tried to put a breakpoint at the beginning of the `OnLayout()` method to understand the effect of the method itself. However, the breakpoint is never reached. For my other custom renderers, I usually created a class like `MyCustomEntry.cs` inside the shared project of the Xamarin application, and I referenced it in my XAML files like that:

```
<controls:CustomEntry Placeholder="..."/>
```

I checked that `controls` reference the correct location on my project, and it does. I thought the `NavigationPageRenderer` should be used like that, but unfortunately, I was wrong, since Visual Studio tells me this:

[image]

Inside the shared Xamarin project, I created an empty class `CustomNavigation`:

```
public class CustomNavigation : NavigationPage { }
```

How do I use the `CustomNavigationRenderer`?

Comment: I think the real question is what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to customize the top navigation bar. Specifically, I plan to change the way the views’ titles are renderer and I also want to change the hamburger icon.

Comment: for changing hamburger button in shell is easy https://stackoverflow.com/a/65081006/5228202

Comment: @Cfun yes: as you can see in that question on SO, the “Dashboard” text is not horizontally centered perfectly.

Comment: This is a known issue in XF you may follow the progress here [Title View's content horizontal aligment](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4848).